# How to convert a .ino Arduino project to CMake?

Tags: c++, arduino, cmake

We have a project written for Arduino that has is compiled through the use of a .ino.

It consists of several .h, 2 of which contain the main equivalent for Arduino, i.e. a setup() and a loop() fcn and they run concurrently (one sending User inputs to the other).

However, to make use of some proprietary code and as part of our new spec, it has to be compiled and uploaded via CMake.

Questions:

1. How does the .ino regulate the main equivalent? Does it just create 2 seperate threads or?
2. How can we replicate this in CMake as none of us know how to compile a program without a central "main". Preferably an answer would have not just in this conversion case, but in general
3. Is there a guide or tutorial to cover the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you'd show us some code.

As for `Cmake`, you can take a look at [Arduino-Cmake](https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake). I have not tested it myself. I'm using `make`. You can take a look at [Sudar's Arduino Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile).

I also wrote a little repo with a simple directory structure for your projects and a lot of documentation. It can help you get started: [Bare Arduino Project](https://github.com/ladislas/Bare-Arduino-Project).

As for you #1 question, the ide *includes* the content of your `.ino` file into the `int main()` function. Here is the real `main` function: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp

I'm surprised your sketch compiles with too `setup` and `loop` functions. Also there is no such things as `threads` in Arduino as is. You need to implement or use a Real Time Operating System or at list some kind of state machine. Can you give us more inputs in that?

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't know who -1'd it. Don't have the rep to +1 it to make up for it.

By 2 setup and loops I mean 2 separate files that contain them, (One file  has the code that takes user input and then sends it to the other) both of which run on the arduino. Just to clarify.

Comment: @user3480291 can you provided a link to the code, github, gist, pastebin, something I can take a look at?